# What is the probability that at least two of the coins are of the same value?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is

> There are 5 coins worth 1 euro, 3 coins worth 2 euros and 2 coins worth 5 euros. 3 coins were taken at random. What is the probability that at least two of them are of the same value?

I took some time to correctly translate it into English, I hope the meaning is clear. In general, my attempt is like this, and it seems to me correct:
$$3\cdot \frac{5}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{8}+3\cdot \frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9}\cdot \frac{7}{8}+3\cdot \frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{9}\cdot \frac{8}{8}+\frac{5}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated.  The probability of getting first a $1$, then a $2$, then a $3$ (in that order) is $\frac 5{10}\times \frac 39\times \frac 28=\frac 1{24}$.  As there are $3!=6$ possible orders, the probability of getting three distinct coins is $\frac 14$, hence the answer to your question is $\frac 34$ (which I believe matches what you wrote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complementary event is when all 3 coins are of different values, hence there are $5\cdot3\cdot2 = 30$ cases when you don't have at least two coins of the same value. In total you have $10 \choose 3$ cases of choosing 3 coins, so the answer is $1 - \frac{30}{10\choose 3}$.

Comment: Thanks! I made things more difficult for no reason :)

Comment: If you had four classes, that would have been more difficult @WrewrWrewtre